# Is there a way to add an instance variable to an existing class through the backend?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, mybatis

I am trying to build a table that can be modified and stored in a sql database. I am using mybatis to access my sql database. I want to be able to take a String from the user and add a column to the existing table that I have. In order to add a column to the sql table, I need to modify the class that fetches the data, and this class needs to have an instance variable added and the constructor modified to be able to fetch the data.

For example, This is one of my Mapper classes that relies on the Employee class to fetch data from the database.

```
@Mapper
public interface EmployeeMapper {
@Select("SELECT * FROM employee")
List<Employee> findEmployees();


@Select("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE list_UserName = #{list};")
List<Employee> employeeForUser(String list);

@Insert("INSERT INTO employee(name, email, position, list_UserName) values (#{name}, #{email}, #{position}, #{list_UserName});")
void addEmployee(Employee employee);

@Delete("DELETE FROM employee WHERE id = #{id}")
void deleteEmployee(int id);
```

}

Employee Class:

```
public class Employee {
private int id;
private String name;
private String email;
private String position;
private String list_UserName;

public Employee(int id, String name, String email, String position, String list_UserName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name =name;
    this.email = email;
    this.position = position;
    this.list_UserName = list_UserName;
}


public String getList_UserName() {
    return list_UserName;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public void setPosition(String position) {
    this.position = position;
}
```

}

Here is my controller for this case:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String newEmployee(Model model, @RequestParam String EmployeeName, @RequestParam String EmployeeEmail, @RequestParam String EmployeePosition, HttpSession session) {
    if(!sessionFound(session.getId())){
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
    if(isNewEmployee(returnUser(session.getId()).getUser_name(), EmployeeName, EmployeeEmail, EmployeePosition)) {
        Employee temp = new Employee(0, EmployeeName, EmployeeEmail, EmployeePosition, returnUser(session.getId()).getUser_name());
        employeeMapper.addEmployee(temp);
        return "redirect:/list";
    }
    model.addAttribute("employeeMessage", "Employee Already Exists");
    return "redirect:/list";
}
```

In this case, I want to be able to alter the table(which I know how to do) and add an instance variable to the Employee class based on the User's request(which I do not know how to do). How do I do that?

Comment: wrong design choice in my opinion: I think it's better to use a `Map` with the new key-value pairs where value can be a custom object

Comment: I agree with @fantaghirocco, this is an example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/827096). The actual problem is how to store and retrieve data that a user defines and that does not belong to the relational DB schema defined at compile time.